# Divide by zero error encountered

Tags: asp.net, sql, divide-by-zero

I'm having an divide by zero error when I launch this SQL query :

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),CaptureTime,106) 'CaptureTime',
        Type,
        CASE WHEN Unit='g/L' THEN (data1* 0.02586) ELSE data1 END As data1,
        CASE WHEN Unit='g/L' THEN nullif(data2* 0.02586,0) ELSE data2 END As data2,
        CASE WHEN Unit='g/L' THEN nullif(data3* 0.02586,0) ELSE data3 END As data3,
        CASE WHEN Unit='g/L' THEN nullif(data1* 0.02586,0) / nullif(data2* 0.02586,0) ELSE (data1/data2) END As Ratio,
        CASE WHEN Unit='g/L' THEN 'ml/L' ELSE 'ml/L' END As data,
        CASE WHEN Unit='g/L' THEN (data4* 0.01129) ELSE data4 END As data4
FROM something 
where Type ='DATA'
and ID='" + Session["name"].ToString() + "'
Order By CONVERT(DateTime, CaptureTime,101) DESC
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to avoid the "divide by zero" error in SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/861778/how-to-avoid-the-divide-by-zero-error-in-sql)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is almost certainly coming from the second line here:

```
CASE WHEN Unit='g/L' THEN nullif(data1* 0.02586,0) / nullif(data2* 0.02586,0) " +
    "ELSE (data1/data2)" +  
    "END As Ratio,"
```

If the unit is not G/L and data2 is 0 you will get an error. Change it to:

```
CASE WHEN Unit='g/L' THEN nullif(data1* 0.02586,0) / nullif(data2* 0.02586,0) " +
    "ELSE (data1/NULLIF(data2, 0))" +  
    "END As Ratio,"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't compute your ratio if you have data2 being equal to zero, because you can't divive by zero, it will always output an error message.

I advise you to add a case :

```
CASE WHEN data2=0 
THEN 0
ELSE
    CASE WHEN Unit='g/L' 
    THEN (data1 * 0.02586) / (data2 * 0.02586) 
    ELSE data1/data2
    END 
END As Ratio,
```

Comment: I think you are mistaking `NULLIF` for `ISNULL` in that line they are dividing by `NULL` if data2 is 0.

Comment: Yes data1 and data2 will be 0 and result will come out 0 how to do???? I want to show result 0