# How to avoid divided by zero error

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to avoid the “divide by zero” error in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861778/how-to-avoid-the-divide-by-zero-error-in-sql)

I have an issue regarding Sql Server divided by zero error.
Sometimes this error and the view it's blocked until I delete the respective row.
Can you please help me and give me some advices in how could I avoid this?
Thanks.

```
CREATE VIEW Acq
AS
SELECT
        ac_id
       ,[Company]
       ,No
       ,[ContractID]
       ,[Seller]
       ,[AcquistionDate]
       ,[Village]
       ,[Commune]
       ,[Area]
       ,[PlotArea]
       ,[FieldNo]
       ,[Topo1]
       ,[Topo2]
       ,[Topo3]
       ,[Topo4]
       ,[Topo5]
       ,[TotalAreaSqm]
       ,[OwnershipTitle]
       ,[CadastralNO]
       ,[Type]
       ,[Price]
       ,[NotaryCosts]
       ,[LandTax]
       ,[OtherTaxes]
       ,[AgentFee]
       ,[CadastralFee]
       ,[TabulationFee]
       ,[CertSarcini]
       ,[ProcuraNO]
       ,cast((isnull(price,0)+isnull(notarycosts,0)+isnull(landtax,0)+isnull(othertaxes,0)+isnull(agentfee,0)+isnull(cadastralfee,0)+isnull(tabulationfee,0)+isnull(certsarcini,0)) as decimal(12,4)) as TotalCosts
       ,cast((isnull(price,0)+isnull(notarycosts,0)+isnull(landtax,0)+isnull(othertaxes,0)+isnull(agentfee,0)+isnull(cadastralfee,0)+isnull(tabulationfee,0)+isnull(certsarcini,0))/(TotalAreaSqm/10000) as decimal(12,4)) as RonPerHa
       ,cast((isnull(price,0)+isnull(notarycosts,0)+isnull(landtax,0)+isnull(othertaxes,0)+isnull(agentfee,0)+isnull(cadastralfee,0)+isnull(tabulationfee,0)+isnull(certsarcini,0))/(TotalAreaSqm/10000*FixHist) as decimal(12,4)) as EurPerHa
       ,[DeclImpunere]
       ,[FixHist]
       ,cast((isnull(price,0)+isnull(notarycosts,0)+isnull(landtax,0)+isnull(othertaxes,0)+isnull(agentfee,0)+isnull(cadastralfee,0)+isnull(tabulationfee,0)+isnull(certsarcini,0))/FixHist as decimal(12,4)) as EurHist
       ,[LandStatus]


FROM      tblAcq
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace expressions like `(TotalAreaSqm/10000)` with `(nullif(TotalAreaSqm,0)/10000)`

This assumes you would like the result to be `null` in the case of division by zero. See the docs [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177562.aspx) for a description of `nullif`.

Answer (score 1):

```
CASE (TotalAreaSQM/1000 <> 0) THEN 'do work' ELSE 'dont do it and pass the 0 or what ever'
```

Gazilion of simmilar stuff you can write.