# Sql server divide by zero issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, t-sql

please someone help me to solve this issue:
I have this select:

```
SELECT Cast(( Isnull(price, 0) + Isnull(notarycosts, 0)
              + Isnull(landtax, 0) + Isnull(othertaxes, 0)
              + Isnull(agentfee, 0) + Isnull(cadastralfee, 0)
              + Isnull(tabulationfee, 0)
              + Isnull(certsarcini, 0) ) / ( totalareasqm / 10000 * fixhist ) AS
                   DECIMAL(12, 4)) AS EurPerHa
```

Sometime i'm getting a divide by zero error and my app it's blocked until i delete the last row from the database.
Could I solve somehow this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to avoid the "divide by zero" error in SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/861778/how-to-avoid-the-divide-by-zero-error-in-sql)

Comment: divide-by-zero is coming from either totalareasqm OR fixhist = 0 so add a WHERE that checks for that in your query

Comment: I would try to do a simple google search of the error before posting it as a question here.

Comment: A [quick search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[sql-server]+divide+by+zero+&submit=search) divide by zero) returned a bunch of threads which probably would have answered the question in a lot less time that it took to post here ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either `TotalAreaSqm` or `FixHist` is 0. As we cannot divide by zero, what should your script do when a zero exists?

I usually see approaches of either make it NULL or use a known value to make it work. I have no idea what a safe value would be.

### Make it null approach

```
select cast((isnull(price,0)+isnull(notarycosts,0)+isnull(landtax,0)+isnull(othertaxes,0)+isnull(agentfee,0)+isnull(cadastralfee,0)+isnull(tabulationfee,0)+isnull(certsarcini,0))/(NULLIF(TotalAreaSqm, 0)/10000*NULLIF(FixHist, 0) as decimal(12,4)) as EurPerHa
```

Answer (score 0):

Checks `FixHist` and `TotalAreaSqm` that are not nulls and not 0.

Code:

```
select CASE WHEN ISNULL(NULLIF(FixHist,0),0) !=0 
                 AND ISNULL(NULLIF(TotalAreaSqm,0),0) !=0
THEN
cast((isnull(price,0)+
isnull(notarycosts,0)+
isnull(landtax,0)+
isnull(othertaxes,0)+
isnull(agentfee,0)+
isnull(cadastralfee,0)+
isnull(tabulationfee,0)+
isnull(certsarcini,0))/(TotalAreaSqm/10000*FixHist) as decimal(12,4))
ELSE 0 END as EurPerHa
```

Comment: incomplete, TotalAreaSqm can be zero as well

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT IIF( TotalAreaSqm*FixHist=0
            ,null
            , cast(
                    ( isnull(price,0)
                      + isnull(notarycosts,0)
                      + isnull(landtax,0)
                      + isnull(othertaxes,0)
                      + isnull(agentfee,0)
                      + isnull(cadastralfee,0)
                      + isnull(tabulationfee,0)
                      + isnull(certsarcini,0) 
                    )
                    /
                   (TotalAreaSqm / 10000 * FixHist ) 
               as decimal(12,4))
           ) as EurPerHa
```

Answer (score -3):

```
( isnull(totalareasqm,1) / 10000 * isnull(fixhist,1) )
```

Comment: That handles NULL values, not when the divisor is zero...

Comment: yeah, totally forgot it, thanks