# ASP VB.net on page load hide details view based on it's value

Tags: vb.net, if-statement, detailsview, visible

I would like to hide a Detailsview control on page load where the control value is 0. The Detailsview links to an sql database and the value displayed is a numerical value from zero upwards.

I have setup the control as follows:

```
<asp:DetailsView Height="25px" Width="60px" ID="dv2cG" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" DataSourceID="ds2cG" BorderWidth="0px" HorizontalAlign="Center" BackColor="#ccd0ff" >
    <Fields>
        <asp:BoundField showheader="false" DataField="2cG" HeaderText="2cG" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="2cG" />
    </Fields>
</asp:DetailsView>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="ds2cG" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MaltingsConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="select sum(case when (name = 'English' and ks2en = '2c' and result like 'G') or (name = 'Mathematics' and ks2ma = '2c' and result like 'G') or (not name = 'Mathematics' and not name = 'English' and ks2av = '2c' and result like 'G') then 1 else 0 end) as '2cG' from student join subject on student.upn=subject.upn where @TeachingGroup = 'Select All' AND ([StuYear] = @StuYear) AND ([DataCollection] = @DataCollection) AND ([Name] = @SubjectName) OR @TeachingGroup &lt;&gt; 'Select All' AND ([StuYear] = @StuYear) AND ([DataCollection] = @DataCollection) AND ([Name] = @SubjectName) AND ([TeachingGroup] = @TeachingGroup)">

<SelectParameters>
    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DdlTeachingGroup" Name="TeachingGroup" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DdlYear" Name="StuYear" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlDataCollection" Name="DataCollection" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DdlSubject" Name="SubjectName" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
 </SelectParameters>
```

I have written the following simple procedure:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    'G column - sets dataitem to visible false where the dataitem equal 0
     If dv2cG.DataItem = 0 Then
         dv2cG.Visible = False
     Else
         dv2cG.Visible = True
     End If

End Sub
```

This hides the DetailsView successfully. However it does so even if the value in the control doesn't equal 1.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this when stumbling upon this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861778/how-to-avoid-the-divide-by-zero-error-in-sql).

I used the `nullif()` function on the sql command e.g.

```
select nullif(sum(case when.....then 1 else 0 end),0) as '2cG'
```