# SQL - SUM-CASE-Divide by zero error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to protect the following statement from a divide by zero error. How can I achieve this?

```
SELECT [MyColumn] = sum( 
   case when v.Process_FundingDt 
   between @begDt and @endDt  
   and v.Loan_Purpose_Desc = 'PURCHASE' 
   then v.Loan_LoanAmt 
   else 0 
   end
 ) / sum (
   case when v.Process_FundingDt 
   between @begDt and @endDt 
   then v.Loan_LoanAmt else 0 
   end
 )
```

Comment: Use a `WHERE EXISTS` to see if the denominator will be non-zero - if it will not, do not select that row to begin with.

Comment: Well, setting a default value of zero in your denominator is a sure way to get a divide by zero error. See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/861778/how-to-avoid-the-divide-by-zero-error-in-sql

Comment: Thanks guys. I added NULL instead of zero and for now, it works. Until the Business Units complain that they want to see a zero. Then its back to the drawing board. But at least for now my boss is happy.

Comment: By the way, I followed post 38 that was linked before posting this question. I couldn't get the statement to evaluate without a syntax error in my situation.

Answer (score 2):

This may help:

```
select [MyColumn] = case when Denominator = 0 then NULL else Numerator / Denominator end
  from (
   select sum( 
   case when v.Process_FundingDt between @begDt and @endDt and v.Loan_Purpose_Desc = 'PURCHASE' then v.Loan_LoanAmt 
     else 0 end ) as Numerator,
   sum (
   case when v.Process_FundingDt between @begDt and @endDt then v.Loan_LoanAmt
     else 0 end ) as Denominator
   ) as Edgar
```

It probably works better with your missing `FROM` clause added.

Of course, it may run afoul of [this](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/691535/aggregates-dont-follow-the-semantics-of-case) feature, depending on what the query optimizer does.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the **NULLIF** method mentioned here: [how to avoid divide by zero error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861778/how-to-avoid-the-divide-by-zero-error-in-sql)

```
SELECT [MyColumn] = sum( 
   case when v.Process_FundingDt 
   between @begDt and @endDt  
   and v.Loan_Purpose_Desc = 'PURCHASE' 
   then v.Loan_LoanAmt 
   else 0 
   end
 ) / NULLIF(sum (
   case when v.Process_FundingDt 
   between @begDt and @endDt 
   then v.Loan_LoanAmt else 0 
   end, 0)
 )
```