# Fastest way to sum the division of two columns that contain 0's and grouped by a third

Tags: sql, database

Lets say we have 3 columns, all integers, the first the `id`, the second `X` and the third `Y`, where `X` is `1` when an instance occurred, `0` when not, and `Y` is `1` when an opportunity for that instance occurred and `0` when not.

```
=================

|  id  | X  | Y | 

=================

| 1    | 1  | 1 | 

| 1    | 0  | 1 | 

| 1    | 0  | 0 | 

| 1    | 1  | 1 | 

| 2    | 0  | 0 | 

| 2    | 0  | 1 |

| 2    | 1  | 1 |  

| .... |    |   | 

=================
```

What I want to do is go through and find basically `X / Y` as a percentage
i.e:

```
(total number of times an instance occurred / total number of opportunities for that to occur, and this all to be grouped by id) * 100
```

The query I have which works (but I wonder if there is a more efficient method) is

```
select id, (CASE WHEN ( sum(Y)) <> 0 THEN ((sum(X))/( sum(Y))) ELSE 0 END) ) * 100) from table GROUP BY id
```

I wonder if it is more efficient to some how do

```
sum(cast(case where Y <> 0 THEN (X/Y) ELSE 0 END 0...
```

Comment: Not quite a duplicate of this issue, but the answers there outline most of the possible approaches: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/861778/how-to-avoid-the-divide-by-zero-error-in-sql

Comment: I wonder if it is more efficient to some how do

sum(cast(case where Y <> 0 THEN (X/Y) ELSE 0 END 0...

Comment: If you deal with `integers` only then you may want to `CAST` either of the sums to force decimal division. I mean it's too late to `CAST` the result.

Comment: Thanks everybody...have solved this now using COALESCE and nullif