# Handling nulls in DATEDIFF calculation

Tags: t-sql, select, sql-server-2012, datediff

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2012 and keep running into the error

> Divide by zero error encountered.

for the statement like below. I want to add a null if the two dates are the same.

```
SELECT 
    sf.TotalPrice / DATEDIFF(day, sf.StartDate,sf.EndDate) as DailyAllocatedRevenue,
    sf.TotalPrice
FROM 
    sftable
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just wrap the `DATEDIFF` in a `NULLIF`:

```
SELECT 

    sf.TotalPrice / NULLIF(DATEDIFF(day, sf.StartDate,sf.EndDate),0) as DailyAllocatedRevenue
    ,sf.TotalPrice

FROM sftable
```

If any of the inputs are `NULL`, or the result is `0`, it will become `NULL` and that propagates through the division.

Comment: @Damien, not really sure the OP has read or understood your warning about NULL propagation!

Comment: @PaulBambury - I think the null propagation is actually a part of what they wanted. I could be wrong but I think they wanted the overall result (for `DailyAllocatedRevenue`) to be `NULL` rather than producing a divide by zero error.

Answer (score 2):

Use `NullIf`  Function in Sql-Server
it Will return null if difference returns 0

See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19631017/simple-way-to-prevent-a-divide-by-zero-error-in-sql)  will help you

```
SELECT 

    sf.TotalPrice / NULLIF(DATEDIFF(day, sf.StartDate,sf.EndDate),0) as DailyAllocatedRevenue
    ,sf.TotalPrice

FROM sftable
```

Answer (score 1):

Try and use

```
case 
     when sd.startdate <> sd.EndDate then sf.TotalPrice / DATEDIFF(day, sf.StartDate, sf.EndDate) as DailyAllocatedRevenue
     else sf.TotalPrice
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
IIF(DATEDIFF(day, sf.StartDate,sf.EndDate)=0,NULL, sf.TotalPrice
/Convert(Decimal(18,4),DATEDIFF(day, sf.StartDate,sf.EndDate)))
```

Should do the trick