# Sql Server ISERROR function

Tags: sql-server, dax

I have a function that returns the format of formula.some part of it----

```
  if(CHARINDEX(@fieldname,@formula)<>0)
            Begin         
                declare @previouschar char = SUBSTRING(@formula, CHARINDEX(@fieldname, @formula)-1, 1), 
                        @nextchar char = SUBSTRING(@formula, CHARINDEX(@fieldname ,@formula)+len(@fieldname), 1)                  
                if(@previouschar in('[',']','(',')','{','}','+','-','/','*') 
                    and @nextchar in ('[',']','(',')','{','}','+','-','/','*'))
                Begin   
                    set @calFormula= replace(@calFormula,@fieldname,' case when FLD'+Convert(varchar,@flid)+' is null OR FLD'+Convert(varchar,@flid)+'='''' then 0.0 else Convert(decimal(18,'+ Convert(varchar,@decimalPlc) +'),FLD'+Convert(varchar,@flid)+' ) end ')
                End
            end
        set @cnt1=@cnt1+1
    End

                    set @calFormula= replace(@calFormula,'[','')
                            set @calFormula= replace(@calFormula,']','')

 return @calFormula
```

I want to implement ISERROR method of DAX in Sql Server Relational Database that would check if any divisor entered is zero then it assigns NULL in calculated formula.How to work for this?Can there be some alternate method like ISERROR in SQL?

Comment: Check for this answer [How to avoid the "divide by zero" error in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861778/how-to-avoid-the-divide-by-zero-error-in-sql). You could replace the divisor with `NULLIF(divisor, 0)`.

Answer (score 0):

Sure.

`IsError(1/0)` will return true (because there is an error)

`IsError(1/1)` will return false (no error).

[Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634214%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)