# Oracle Error when dividing by Zero

Tags: sql, oracle, if-statement, case

I have a query where I need to get a certain number divided by 2 fields in 2 columns.

shelve.total_qty/(GREATEST(NVL(y.FORECAST_QUANTITY, 0), NVL(z.sales, 0))/7) as Shelve_DOC

I get the notorious error.

ORA-01476: divisor is equal to zero
01476. 00000 -  "divisor is equal to zero"
*Cause:
*Action:

I have read around I need a CASE/IF but I'm not sure how to..

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There is a neat way using nullif

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/861778/how-to-avoid-the-divide-by-zero-error-in-sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
     CASE WHEN (GREATEST(NVL(y.FORECAST_QUANTITY, 0), NVL(z.sales, 0))/7) = 0 THEN null
          ELSE shelve.total_qty/(GREATEST(NVL(y.FORECAST_QUANTITY, 0), NVL(z.sales, 0))/7)
     END Shelve_DOC
  FROM ...
 WHERE ....
```

Should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
CASE WHEN NVL(y.FORECAST_QUANTITY,0) <= 0 AND NVL(z.sales,0) <= 0
     THEN NULL
     ELSE shelve.total_qty/(GREATEST(NVL(y.FORECAST_QUANTITY, 0), NVL(z.sales, 0))/7)
     END AS Shelve_DOC
```

Comment: This worked perfectly as well! Glad I can select two answers.