# Add a column into a select for calculation

Tags: sql, sql-server, formula

I have 2 columns from a table and i want to add a third column to output the result of a calculation

select statement at the moment is:

```
select revenue, cost
from   costdata
```

my 2 columns are revenue and cost

table name: costdata

my formula is:  `= ((revenue - cost)/ revenue)*100`

I want the third column to be named 'result'

any idea on how to do this in a select statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query:

```
SELECT revenue, 
       cost,
       CASE WHEN revenue <> 0 
            THEN ((revenue - cost) / revenue) * 100
       ELSE 0 END As result
FROM   costdata
```

Comment: if revenue is decimal or float then its ok else you have to cast it into decimal to get exact result.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT revenue
     , cost
     , ((revenue - cost) / revenue) * 100 As result
FROM   costdata
```

You mentioned in the comments that you get a divide by zero error. This wll occur when `revenue` equals zero.

What you want to happen in this scenario is up to you but this should get you started

```
SELECT revenue
     , cost
     , CASE WHEN revenue = 0 THEN
         0
       ELSE
         ((revenue - cost) / revenue) * 100
       END As result 
FROM   costdata
```

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
select revenue, cost,((revenue - cost)/ revenue)*100 AS result
from   costdata
```

Comment: I think your 'revenue' returning 0 in some cases. You have to check that.

Comment: You can use 
Select dividend / nullif(divisor, 0)

source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/861778/how-to-avoid-the-divide-by-zero-error-in-sql

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT revenue, cost, ((revenue - cost)/ revenue)*100 AS result FROM costdata
```