# SQL Server (Avoiding Dividing by a null value)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query:

```
UPDATE FinanceTable
SET    PercentageComplete = (SELECT ( Sum(LabourFinance.HoursTaken / LabourFinance.Hours) / Count(LabourID) )
                             FROM   LabourFinance
                             WHERE  FinanceID = (SELECT TOP 1 FinanceID
                                                 FROM   FinanceTable
                                                 ORDER  BY changedate DESC)
                             GROUP  BY FinanceID)
WHERE  FinanceID = (SELECT TOP 1 FinanceID
                    FROM   FinanceTable 
                    ORDER  BY changedate DESC)
```

what this query does is select 1 specific cell based upon a changedate, and i am using that to update a cost value in my FinanceTable.

this scenario is causing me the issue:

- I have allocated 100 hours to complete a task
- `HoursTaken` is currently 0 after inserting into the table as ive not started yet
- when calculating `PercntageComplete`, SQL Server will not let me do (0 / 100), therefore causing an error...

How can i prevent this? my desired outcome would be `PercentageComplete = 0%`

thanks for any input :) below is the error message i get by runnig the query above

[image]

Comment: `0/100` should be absolutely fine, and return `0`. You get problems with `0` when it the divisor, not the dividend.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: So where are you getting a null value?

Comment: Possible problems are 
Either you have allocated '0' hours for task 
or 
the count of labors for the condition is'0'.Apart from this i see no issue

Comment: It would also help (not just us but you and anyone else reading your SQL) if you formatted it in a nice way. I would suggest sticking to all upper or lower case for SQL keywords for example, and use indentation.

Comment: @crezzer7 - Whether your query is correct. i see error in your query

Comment: Correct your query .It has syntactical errors

Comment: Give a Try to my updated answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer This

[How to avoid the “divide by zero” error in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861778/how-to-avoid-the-divide-by-zero-error-in-sql)

```
UPDATE FinanceTable
SET    PercentageComplete = (SELECT COALESCE (Sum(COALESCE (LabourFinance.HoursTaken / NULLIF(LabourFinance.Hours, 0), 0)) / NULLIF(Count(LabourID), 0), 0)
                             FROM   LabourFinance
                             WHERE  FinanceID = (SELECT TOP 1 FinanceID
                                                 FROM   FinanceTable
                                                 ORDER  BY changedate DESC)
                             GROUP  BY FinanceID)
WHERE  FinanceID = (SELECT TOP 1 FinanceID
                    FROM   FinanceTable
                    ORDER  BY changedate DESC)
```

Comment: how do i apply that to my scenario though, ive seen this already and failed trying to get it to work

Comment: updated with your query.Try it

Comment: I tried using COALESCE earlier, what is it doing? and thankyou for the help

Comment: COALESCE returns the current value of the first expression that initially does not evaluate to NULL.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms190349.aspx

Comment: cheers pal, this would have taken me ages to work out...