# how to handle Zero divided by zero in sqlserver

Tags: sql-server

how we can handle `0/0` in SQL Server? I used `select nullif(0)/nullif(0)` but ..

> Msg 8134, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Divide by zero error encountered.

Comment: Could you post your actual query?

Comment: update generalRegionWise set [Collection %] = convert(VARCHAR,convert(MONEY,100.0 * ([Total Collection]) / isnull(nullif([Billed Amount], 0), 0)),1) + '%'  The [Total Collection] and [Billed Amount] both are dynamic and can contain 0,0 values

Comment: Edit your question and put in the query.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to avoid the "divide by zero" error in SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/861778/how-to-avoid-the-divide-by-zero-error-in-sql)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `NULLIF` like this something like this

```
SELECT 0/NULLIF(0,0)
```

If you want the result as 0 when you encounter `NULL`, then use `ISNULL/COALESCE`

```
SELECT COALESCE(0/NULLIF(0,0),0)
```

In your query, you only need to move the `ISNULL` to check like this  `isnull(([Total Collection]) / nullif([Billed Amount], 0), 0)`

```
update generalRegionWise set [Collection %] = 
    convert(VARCHAR,convert(MONEY,100.0 * isnull(([Total Collection]) / nullif([Billed Amount], 0), 0)),1) + '%'
```

It is recommended to specify the length when converting to `VARCHAR` like this `convert(VARCHAR(50),...` In your case it will take the default length of 30.

Answer (score 1):

here are a few more examples.

```
DECLARE @numerator Int = 0
DECLARE @denominator Int = 0

SELECT ISNULL(NULLIF(@numerator, @denominator),0) AS Result;

SELECT CASE WHEN @denominator = 0 
       THEN 0 
       ELSE @numerator / @denominator 
       END AS Results
```

Hope this helps.