# Can you help me with Divided by zero Error

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Select ‘contribution amount/rate’= isnull(CAST(priceAmountMax/priceAmountpercetage as Decimal (15,3)),0)
From PriceList
```

I am sharing a part of my query. I’m using SQL Server. According to my query result I get:

> divide by zero error encountered.

How can I edit this query. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What's confusing you about the error? It's fairly clear and a common type of error in any programming language.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid the "divide by zero" error in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861778/how-to-avoid-the-divide-by-zero-error-in-sql)

Comment: Do those funny quotes (`‘`) work in SQL Server? (They give me a syntax error).

Answer (score 0):

Put `NULLIF` around `priceAmountpercetage`, so that the division is against null instead of zero:

```sql
isnull(CAST(priceAmountMax / nullif(priceAmountpercetage, 0) as Decimal (15,3)),0)
```

Comment: @GordonLinoff I suspect people getting annoyed about me answering when there is already a duplicate. You're welcome to vote to close the question as duplicate, but the answer, as you say is the correct one

Answer (score -1):

You can convert the result to `NULL` when divider is `0` as follows:

```
Select case when priceAmountpercetage <> 0 
            then isnull(CAST(priceAmountMax/priceAmountpercetage as Decimal (15,3)),0) 
        end
From PriceList
```