# Division by zero in SQL statement how to avoid specific record if it returns division by zero

Tags: sql, delphi

I am trying to make a statement that takes a players goals scored and then divides by games played.
If the player has played 0 games division of 0 will occur. How do I "skip" or ignore this and display N/A instead for goals per game?
This is what I currently have:

```
SELECT PlayerName, PlayerSurname, GamesPlayed, GoalsScored, ROUND(GoalsScored/GamesPlayed ,2) AS GoalsPerGame
FROM tblPlayers , tblStatistics 
WHERE tblPlayers.PlayerID = tblStatistics.PlayerID 
ORDER BY GoalsScored DESC
```

I am doing it in delphi 10.3 so the joining of the tables is done in the where statement, but that doesn't effect the general problem.
if I were doing it for one record I would have done

```
if tblStatistics['GamesPlayed'] = 0 then
begin
qryStatsStatic.SQL.Clear;
qryStatsStatic.SQL.Add('
SELECT PlayerName, PlayerSurname, GamesPlayed, GoalsScored, "N/A" AS GoalsPerGame
FROM tblPlayers , tblStatistics 
WHERE tblPlayers.PlayerID = tblStatistics.PlayerID 
ORDER BY GoalsScored DESC');
qryStatistics.open;
end;
```

But my problem is for multiple records.

Comment: In Pascal, a string literal is surrounded by apostrophes.

Comment: Sorry forgot to include it here, I did have the apostrophes in my code, just forgot to add it here.

Comment: When asking a question about SQL, it's important to also add a tag for the specific DBMS you're using, as functionality and syntax varies widely between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try an SQL Union:

```
SELECT PlayerName, PlayerSurname, GamesPlayed, GoalsScored, 
       ROUND(GamesPlayed/GoalsScored ,2) AS GoalsPerGame
FROM tblPlayers , tblStatistics 
WHERE tblPlayers.PlayerID = tblStatistics.PlayerID
  AND GoalsScored <> 0
UNION
SELECT PlayerName, PlayerSurname, GamesPlayed, GoalsScored, 0
FROM tblPlayers , tblStatistics 
WHERE tblPlayers.PlayerID = tblStatistics.PlayerID
  AND GoalsScored = 0
ORDER BY GoalsScored DESC
```

Comment: This solution gives me the error: "floating point dicide by zero at 0x76c02a27"

Comment: @OdinMostert Please don't re-type your error messages if you're prone to mis-type them - copy them instead. Also exchange `GamesPlayed` (dividend) with `GoalsScored` (divisor) - you want to avoid a divisor of 0, while a dividend of 0 is irrelevant.

Comment: Sorry, swapped fields.

Answer (score 5):

You may use a short `nullif` function that is present in most of the popular DBMSes:

```
select
  ...,
  ROUND(GamesPlayed/nullif(GoalsScored, 0) ,2) as GoalsPerGame
...
```

Comment: According to [How to avoid the “divide by zero” error in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/861791/4299358) `GoalsScored` must not be NULL when doing it this way. Also I miss the explanation that a division by NULL computes to NULL.

Comment: @OdinMostert . . . This is the best solution.

Comment: When running this in delphi 10.3 it gives the error :'Undefined function "nullif" in expression'.  It is possibly an error with this version of delphi, I know with delphi I can't use join to link tables either.

Comment: " It is possibly an error with this version of delphi"  No, the RDBMS is telling you that it does not support `nullif`.

Comment: @OdinMostert Didn't expect to have problems with this, but I have to ask as per [SQL tag question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql): what is your DBMS? Delphi is out of the context when the query is already (running) inside the DBMS and vice versa: DBMS is out of the context when you've fetched the data to the  Delphi side.

Comment: @OdinMostert - If your DBMS doesn't support `nullif()` then replace `nullif(GoalsScored, 0)` with `case when GoalsScored <> 0 then GoalsScored end`

Answer (score 1):

SQL has CASE statement that only executes until it finds a match.

```
CASE WHEN COALESCE(GamesPlayed,0) = 0 THEN 0
     ELSE ROUND(GoalsScored/GamesPlayed,2) 
END AS GoalsPerGame
```

Also goals per game would be goals/games.

Comment: This solution gives me the error message "Unspecified error" . I don't know what causes this error, it showed me this error before when my one columns name was "position" and when I changed it the playerPosition it worked.

Comment: It should be obvious: this is the replacement for the existing `ROUND(...) AS GoalsPerGame` or `"N/A" AS GoalsPerGame` part. In other words: one column to select.