# How to calculate a percentage while avoiding a 'division by zero' error in sql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Before I start I want to first highlight that this is not a sql question per se even though I stated 'in sql'. the reason for that is because I'm creating it in sql. This is a percentage question in whichever programming language. now what I'm trying to do is get a percentage of something. in order to get a percentage the calculation goes as;

```
amount * 100 / full amount = amount in percentage

eg. 0.30 * 100 / 250 000 = 0.00012%

which means that 0.30 is worth 0.00012% of 250 000.
```

now where the problem starts is that the above equation in any programming language creates a `division by zero` error. I think most of us are familiar with what a `division by zero` error is. I'm not going to waste words explaining. since I'm using sql many would say use a `NULLIF` function to return null instead of a value but in this case the problem is. the formula I'm writing, for it to work properly, it needs the value(percentage) amount. here is the code.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION calc_likes_points(p_artist VARCHAR(150))
    RETURNS INT
AS 
$$

DECLARE

INTER          INT;
INTER_2        INT;
AUD            BIGINT;
P_O_E          INT;
P_O_E_2        INT;
P_O_E_D        NUMERIC;
N_E_P_P_L      BIGINT;
ENG            INT;
ENG_LIKES      BIGINT;
V_O_E          SMALLINT;
T_C_A          INT;
T_L            INT;

BEGIN

    /* abbreviations meanings */
    
    --INTER - Interaction
    --INTER - Interaction 2
    --AUD - Audience
    --ENG_LIKES - Engagement likes
    --ENG - engagement
    --V_O_E - value of engagement
    --P_O_E - percentage of engagement
    --P_O_E_D - percentage of engagement decimal
    --N_E_P_P_L - no of engagement per points likes
    --T_C_A - Total calculated amount
    --T_L - total likes

    /* variables */

    --interaction

    WITH TEMP AS(
    SELECT COUNT(no_of_post) AS POST FROM machine_twitter 
    WHERE artist = p_artist
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT COUNT(no_of_post) AS POST FROM machine_facebook 
    WHERE artist = p_artist)
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT COUNT(no_of_post) AS POST FROM machine_instagram 
    WHERE artist = p_artist)
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT COUNT(no_of_post) AS POST FROM machine_youtube 
    WHERE artist = p_artist)
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT COUNT(no_of_post) POST FROM machine_tiktok 
    WHERE artist = p_artist)
    )
    SELECT SUM(POST) FROM temp INTO INTER;

    --audience

    WITH TEMP AS(
    SELECT MAX(no_of_followers) AS FOLLOWERS FROM machine_twitter
    WHERE artist = p_artist
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT MAX(no_of_followers) AS FOLLOWERS FROM machine_facebook
    WHERE artist = p_artist) 
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT MAX(no_of_followers) AS FOLLOWERS FROM machine_instagram
    WHERE artist = p_artist) 
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT MAX(no_of_followers) AS FOLLOWERS FROM machine_youtube
    WHERE artist = p_artist) 
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT MAX(no_of_followers) AS FOLLOWERS FROM machine_tiktok
    WHERE artist = p_artist)
    )
    SELECT SUM(FOLLOWERS) FROM TEMP INTO AUD;

    --likes engagement

    WITH TEMP AS(
    SELECT likes FROM machine_twitter WHERE
    artist = p_artist
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT likes FROM machine_facebook WHERE
    artist = p_artist)
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT likes FROM machine_youtube WHERE
    artist = p_artist)
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT likes FROM machine_instagram WHERE
    artist = p_artist)
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT likes FROM machine_tiktok WHERE
    artist = p_artist)
    )
    SELECT SUM(likes) FROM TEMP INTO ENG_LIKES;

    /* formula */

    /*

    aud / 100 * inter = percentage of engagement
    engagement * percentage = no of engagement per points likes

    */

    /* equation */

    INTER_2 := 100 * INTER;
    P_O_E := AUD / INTER_2;
    SELECT ceiling(P_O_E) INTO P_O_E_2;
    SELECT quote_literal(0.P_O_E_2);
    SELECT CAST ('0.P_O_E_2') AS float) INTO P_O_E_D;
    N_E_P_P_L := ENG_LIKES * P_O_E_D;

    SELECT ENG_LIKES/N_E_P_P_L INTO T_C_A;

    SELECT total_likes(T_C_A) INTO T_L;

    RETURN T_L;

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

now as you can see from the equation section I changed the formula from `inter * 100 / aud` to `aud/ 100 * inter` to avoid the `division by zero` error part. now this stop-gap solution for `division by zero` creates a different problem for my formula. in order to get the percentage of engagement the output of `aud/100*inter` needs to be in numeric instead of integer which is what this formula gives us. now what I am looking for is a way to convert it to numeric but I'm struggling because I just cant find a way. the `ceiling` and `quote_literal` functions don't work. they create their own errors. Is there a way around this?

Comment: `NULLIF` should do the trick. check [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861778/how-to-avoid-the-divide-by-zero-error-in-sql)

Comment: Don't spam the tags. This is not tsql for SQL Server.

Comment: @NagibMahfuz this work in other scenario's but it doesn't work with my formula. it stops it and returns ``NULL`` . which is counterproductive to what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: When you use `dividend / NULLIF(divisor, 0)` it will return `0` not `NULL`. so `Divide by zero` error will be gone and output will be `0`

Comment: Your formula `aud/100*inter` results in as integer  because each expression/value in it are integers so Postgres performs integer arithmetic. All you need is to force decimal arithmetic. Try `aud::numeric/100*inter` or even just `aud/100.0*inter`.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the interaction query as

```
    SELECT CASE WHEN SUM(POST)= 0 
                     OR SUM(POST) IS NULL THEN 1
                ELSE SUM(POST)
           END
    FROM TEMP INTO INTER;
```