# SQL Server use the new column name in other column in view

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression, lateral-join

I use SQL Server, and I created view and added new column which contain mathematical equation

Let's say I have this:

```
create view 
as
    select 
        a.date, a.sale, a.buy,
        profit = a.sale - a.buy,
        profit_prs = (a.sale - a.buy) / a.sale 
    from 
        tableA a
```

In line 5 how can I use `[profit]` column in `[profit_prs]` expression
to be like this:

```
profit_prs = profit  / a.sale
```

Comment: You will need to use a derived-table or a CTE to add a new "logical step" to the query, as ISO SQL does not let you refer to newly-defined column-expressions in the same query step.

Comment: Also, consider using `WITH SCHEMABINDING` to protect your `VIEW` from breaking-changes to `tableA` - and you should schema-qualify your object-names too (which helps performance).

Comment: BTW, your query will fail if `a.sale == 0` due to divide-by-zero: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861778/how-to-avoid-the-divide-by-zero-error-in-sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **First-off**: you need to address the divide-by-zero error that's looming in your query...

  - Change `(a.sale - a.buy) / a.sale` to `( a.sale - a.buy ) / NULLIF( a.sale, 0.0 )` - that way you'll get a `NULL` in `profit_prs` instead of your query aborting entirely.

    - Moving on....
- ISO/ANSI SQL does not allow a `SELECT` projection to refer to new column expressions in the same query "level" (i.e. within the same `SELECT` clause of the same derived-table or CTE or other table expression).

  - Some RDBMS extend SQL to allow it, such as MySQL.
- Instead, uou will need to use a new derived-table or a CTE to add a new "logical step" to the query which will `SELECT` your base-table's `date`, `sale`, and `buy` columns, and define the new `profit` column.

  - ...and the next (outer-er) `SELECT` can then define the `profit_prs` column based on the previous step's `profit` column.
  - However, when you do this, the end-result is very verbose and probably harder to maintain:

This is what the `VIEW` looks like when using a new CTE to represent the inner step:

```sql
CREATE VIEW dbo.MyView AS

WITH q1 AS (

    SELECT
        a.date,
        a.sale,
        a.buy,
        profit = ( a.sale - a.buy )
    FROM
        dbo.TableA AS a
)
SELECT
    q1.date,
    q1.sale,
    q1.buy,
    q1.profit,
    profit_prs = q1.profit / NULLIF( a.sale, 0.0 )
FROM
    q1;
```

Whereas if you don't mind the repetition of `( a.sale - a.buy )` you still end-up with a much shorter query:

```sql
CREATE VIEW dbo.MyView AS

SELECT
    a.date,
    a.sale,
    a.buy,
    profit     = ( a.sale - a.buy ),
    profit_prs = ( a.sale - a.buy ) / NULLIF( a.sale, 0.0 )
FROM
    dbo.TableA AS a;
```

Answer (score 0):

That’s a good spot to use `cross apply`; you can move the calculation to to an inline table of values, then reuse it as you wish in the `select` clause:

```
create view myview as
select a.date, a.sale, a.buy,
    x.profit,
    x.profit / nullif(a.sale, 0) profit_prs
from tableA a
cross apply ( values (a.sale - a.buy) ) x(profit)
```